# Linear Regression - Get Feature Importance using MinMaxScaler() - Extremely large coefficients

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, regression, feature-selection

I'm trying to get the feature importances for a Regression model. I have 58 independent variables and one dependent variables. Most of the independent variables are numerical and some are binary.

First I used this:

```
X = dataset.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y = dataset[['y']]

# define the model
model = LinearRegression()
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y)
# get importance
importance = model.coef_[0]
print(model.coef_)
print(importance)
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

and got the following results:
[Feature Importance Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwa1l.png)

Then I used MinMaxScaler() to scale the data before fitting the model:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
dataset[dataset.columns] = scaler.fit_transform(dataset[dataset.columns])
print(dataset)

X = dataset.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y = dataset[['y']]

# define the model
model = LinearRegression()
# fit the model
model.fit(X, y)
# get importance
importance = model.coef_[0]
print(model.coef_)
print(importance)
# summarize feature importance
for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
# plot feature importance
pyplot.bar([x for x in range(len(importance))], importance)
pyplot.show()
```

which led to the following plot:
[Feature Importance Plot after using MinMaxScaler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEYiA.png)

As you can see in the upper left corner it is 1e11, which means the largest values are negative 60 billion. What am I doing wrong here? And is it even the right approach to use MinMaxScaler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regression analysis, the magnitude of your coefficients is not necessarily related to their importance. The most common criteria to determine the importance of independent variables in regression analysis are p-values. Small p-values imply high levels of importance, whereas high p-values mean that a variable is not statistically significant. You should only use the magnitude of coefficients as a measure for feature importance when your model is penalizing variables. That is, when the optimization problem has L1 or L2 penalties, like lasso or ridge regressions.

`sklearn` does not report p-values though. I recommend running the same regression using `statsmodels.OLS`. For all other models, including trees, ensembles, neural networks, etc., you should use `feature_importances_` to determine the individual importance of each independent variable.

By using `model.coef_` as a measure of feature importance, you are only taking into account the magnitude of the betas. If this really is what you are interested in, try `numpy.abs(model.coef_[0])`, because betas can be negative too.

As for your use of `min_max_scaler()`, you are using it correctly. However, you are transforming the entire dataset, when really, you are only supposed to re-scale your independent variables.

```py
X = dataset.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y = dataset['y']
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
print(X)
```

By using `scaler.fit_transform(dataset[dataset.columns])` you were rescaling ALL the columns in your `dataset` object, including your dependent variable. In fact, your code is equivalent to `scaler.fit_transform(dataset)`, as you were selecting all the columns in `dataset`.

Typically, you should only re-scale your data if you suspect that outliers are affecting your estimator. By re-scaling your data, the beta coefficients are no longer interpretable (or at least not as intuitive). This happens because a given beta no longer indicates the change in the dependent variable caused by a marginal change in the corresponding independent variable.

Finally, this should not be an issue, but just to be safe, make sure that the scaler is not changing your binary independent variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply! "I would like to start off by saying that in regression analysis, the magnitude of your coefficients is not necessarily related to their importance." - Is there any way I can find the "importance" of my coefficients then?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/ - I used the model.coef_ method because I found it in this article

Comment: Hey! I updated the answer slightly. In regression analysis, you should use p-values rather than the magnitude of coefficients. Sklearn does not report p-values, so I recommend running the same regression using `statsmodels.OLS`.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look! Any chance I could quickly ask you some additional questions in a chat? It's simpler than using the comment function

Comment: Sure. Is there a chat on stack overflow?

Comment: There is but I just realized that one needs to have at least 20 reputation and I'm only at 11, so it probably won't work... Unless you are able to invite me to a chat possibly? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-can-i-start-a-chat-with-a-particular-user

Comment: Haha. I upvoted one of your old posts. You now have 21 rep. Inv me if you'd like.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226584/arturo-sbr-pyth-qwertz-discussion here's the room :)

Comment: please check the chat again when/if you have time :)